# Problem Advanced Custom Fields PRO

Tags: plugins, custom-field, woocommerce-offtopic

I added it but the badges don't appear

I hope to help me solve the problem

I'd like to show badges like this

[image]

I tried but couldn't

```
echo '<div class="wub-badges-wrapper">';
$badges = get_field('badges_user'); 
    if( $badges && in_array('Verified', $badges) ): ?><a  class="wub-badge" id="membership_duration" data-tooltip="Verified account"><img  class='avatar avatar-64 photo' height='64' width='64' src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/Verified-account.svg" data-tooltip="Verified account" title="Verified account"></a>
<?php endif;
```

Comment: Are there multiple badges a user can have? Can you please screenshot your Advanced Custom Fields configuration for the badges? That will give us better insight into the issue. Also, please add this line of code before the `if` so we can see what is saved in the badge: `print_r($badges);`

Comment: You may want to contact ACF support directly since they have plugin-specific expertise. But as Tom said to help, we would need to know more about how you have the fields set up.